# Авто-заполнение формы и отправка на сайт

Tags: python, requests

Всем добрый вечер!
Столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне нужно чтобы python заходил на сайт. Пример: https://shafa.ua/login/registration?next=/
Вписывал номер телефона и отправлял данные.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: это новый вид маркетинга? (шутка). Было бы не полохо увидеть вашу попытку реализовать это, а дальше поможем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium webdriver в помощь

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe") # ссылка на драйвер,зависит от браузера найти его несложно просто загугли и скачай

driver.get(https://shafa.ua/login/registration?next=/)

element = driver.find_element_by_name("...") # сюда вводишь имя элемента куда нужно вводить номер,смотри через код элемента на странице 
element.send_keys("88005553535") #сюда номер вводишь который нужно

button = driver.find_element_by_name("...").click() # сюда вводишь элемент кнопки
```

Также кроме имени  можно искать элементы по айди,классу,атрибутам и по xpath. Последнее самое удобное

Comment: а все увидел. спасибо